# Unable to uninstall wine in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and recently I have installed wine and it was not able to find the `.dll` files so I ran the command `sudo apt-get remove winehq` it showed that the wine has been uninstalled but when I type `which wine` I am getting the output `/usr/bin/wine` it seems it hasn't been uninstalled completely and when I try `sudo apt-get purge wine*` I am getting the following errors

```
E: Unable to locate package winehq.key
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'winehq.key'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'winehq.key'
```

Output of `apt list --installed | grep wine`:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts. 
wine-devel/bionic,now 4.0~rc3~bionic amd64 [installed,automatic] 
wine-devel-amd64/bionic,now 4.0~rc3~bionic amd64 [installed,automatic] 
wine-devel-i386/bionic,now 4.0~rc3~bionic i386 [installed,automatic] 
winehq-devel/bionic,now 4.0~rc3~bionic amd64 [installed] winetricks/bionic,bionic,now 0.0+20180217-1 all [installed]
```

What am I doing wrong and how to complete remove everying that is related to wine and install install it properly

Comment: Please run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Please explain clearly all the different ways you used to install Wine, including any failed attempts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can uninstall all dependencies related to `wine`

```
sudo apt-get remove --autoremove wine-*
```

Comment: worked for me on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: For me too, on Ubuntu 20.04, and unlike the solution proposed in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have installed wine's development version (a.k.a. beta) which can be unstable sometimes. To remove wine, run:

```
sudo apt autoremove wine-devel wine-devel-amd64 wine-devel-i386 winehq-devel winetricks
```

I'll recommend you to install wine-stable to have a wine with minimal bugs. To install it run:

```
sudo apt install wine-stable
```