# Uninstall Wine from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wine

I tried installing wine and saw that its consuming very big space so I didn't installed it completely and deleted folder named wine but the storage is not cleared so how can I remove it completely?
I tried this command to install it `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

```
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable


and tried these commands to remove it
sudo apt-get --purge remove wine
cd $HOME
rm -r .wine
rm .config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -r .local/share/applications/wine
rm .local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm .local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine
```

Comment: How did you install it ?

Comment: Followed all the command on their website.@SorenA

Comment: So you expect me/us at AU to read through arbitrary websites to guess or workout what you did? Please update your questions on how you installed wine (commands and results), and what you tried to uninstall, then you might get some help.

Comment: Yes done @SorenA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to uninstall wine in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105632/unable-to-uninstall-wine-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you removed all traces of wine but installing wine also installed a lot of dependencies. You can remove them with `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`

That will remove packages that were installed automatically and are no longer needed.
The packages themself are probably cached in your system. You can also remove them with `sudo apt-get clean`
If you have never done that, it will free a lot of space.

Answer (score -1):

$ sudo apt autoremove wine-stable

adding stable at the end helped for me,if any issue or suggestion,then do reply, Thanks :)